# Why does the ion thruster trust not assume a simpler form?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, rocket-science, propulsion

Consider the thrust of an ion thruster in a vacuum as described by [Dan M. Goebel and Ira Katz, Fundamentals of Electric
Propulsion: Ion and Hall Thrusters](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/SciTechBook/series1/Goebel__cmprsd_opt.pdf). From the conservation of momentum, the trust exerted on an ion thruster by the ion is
$$T=v_e \dot m$$
where $\dot m$ is the time derivative of the mass of the thruster and $v_e$ is the terminal speed of the exhaust relative to the thruster. Should the following relation not hold?
$$\dot m = MnAv_e$$
where $n$ is the numerical density of the exhaust particle at the nozzle exit, $M$ is the mass per particle and $A$ the cross sectional area of the nozzle exit.

Equation $(2.3-7)$ of the book states
$$\dot m=\frac{IM}q.$$
Should it not be that $I=nqAv_e$? Is this not true?

Putting the above together and keeping in mind the conservation of energy, we arrive at
$$T = MnAv_e^2=2nqAV$$
where $V$ is the electric potential or voltage through which the ion is accelerated. This is much simpler than Equation $(2.3-8)$ of the book. Why does the book not write out this simpler expression? It seems the authors consider $I$ as an independent variable. Why?

Comment: Notice that your equation $\dot m = MnAv_e$ is wrong dimensionally speaking. On the LHS you have $M/T$ and on the RHS $L^3M/T$

Comment: @JD_PM: The numerical density $n$ is the number of particles per unit volume and thus with unit $M/L^3$ which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Should $\dot m = MnAv_e$ relation not hold?

Yes, what you are essentially stating is mass flow through an area $A$ (which, by definition, is the mass going through $A$ per second). You can always define $\rho := Mn$, to get the more familiar mass flow rate expression $\dot m = \rho Av_e$

> Should it not be that $I_b=nqv_e$? Is this not true?

$I_b$ is the ion beam current. Hence $[I_b] = \frac Q T$. Notice that your equation for $I_b$ yields $[I_b] = \frac{Q}{L^2 T}$, so you need to include the $A$ factor. We have

$$I = \frac{q \dot m}{M} = \frac{q \rho A v_e}{M} = qn A v_e$$

Your equation for the spacecraft thrust is OK.

Comment: The loss of $A$ in my question was a simple typo, as I had factor $A$ appearing where it belongs everywhere else. I have added it to the expression for $I$ in my question now. Also, the reason I separate out $Mn$ as opposed to combine them into $\rho:=Mn$ is that my final expression of $T$ cancels $M$ which is important. So you agree with my formula, right? But my question is really why the book takes $I$ as an independent variable. Do you think it is their oversight?

Comment: I do not think it is a mistake. To me, the authors included the variable $I_b$ due to writing style. They first introduced the definition of mass flow rate in a general way ($\dot m_p := QM$; number of particles per second $Q$ times its mass $M$) and then looked at the case of ion thrust. So it is natural they wanted to write down the corresponding expression for the ion's mass flow rate $\dot m_i=\frac{IM}q$. However, your equations describe the same physics. They look OK to me.